# Excel, VBA, can't get cell from row and column ID

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on the function Worksheet_Change and I have an issue.
I cannot get a cell using the row and the column ID.

I have tried a lot of solutions but nothing.

Could you help me please?

This is my script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim myCell As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("G4:N19")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
Is Nothing Then

    selectedRow = Target.Row
    myColumn = Range("F" & 1).Column

    With Sheets(1)
        ' selectedRow = 16, myColumn = 6
        myCell = .Cells(selectedRow, myColumn)
        ' myCell is empty
        MsgBox myCell

    End With

End If
End Sub
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just FYI, this is pointless: `Range(Target.Address)` - you should just use `Target` since it is a Range object already.

Comment: Ok I will do that. Thank you. This part of code is a copy/past from support microsoft ^^

Comment: Try replacing the `1` in the `Sheets(1)` with the actual name: `Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Comment: @Rory: I remove the ".Address" but there is an error when I update my cell. I think a declaration is missing. So I keep it.

Comment: You need to replace the whole `Range(Target.Address)` with `Target` not just remove `.Address`.  Target is a  range object and the unnecessary conversion to a string then back to a range slows down the code, albeit minuscule.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry... I fixed that. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/set-statement?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) when assigning a range (object) variable (as you did earlier in the code).

```
Set myCell = .Cells(selectedRow, myColumn)
```

You should always declare all your variables too (and note Rory's point). The myColumn line looks somewhat redundant too.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim KeyCells As Range
Dim myCell As Range
Dim selectedRow As Long
Dim myColumn As Long

Set KeyCells = Range("G4:N19")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target) Is Nothing Then
    selectedRow = Target.Row
    myColumn = Range("F1").Column
    With Sheets(1)
        ' selectedRow = 16, myColumn = 6
        Set myCell = .Cells(selectedRow, myColumn)
        ' myCell is empty
        MsgBox myCell.Value
    End With
End If

End Sub
```